# Use MySQL for storing secrets in Strongswan VPN

Tags: mysql, ipsec, strongswan, ikev2

I have a working Strongswan IKEv2 VPN, i uses eap-mschapv2 as right auth.
It's working fine as long as I use the ipsec.secrets file to store the user credentials.

```
# ipsec.secrets file
: RSA vpn-server-key.pem
arav %any : EAP "accessit"
```

But I want to change it to store these secrets in a MySQL database.
I've connected the mysql database in the sql.conf file i just want to know how to insert these user credentials in MySQL table.

On refering this guide: https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/SQLite

It doesn't store the secrets in plain text but it uses any kind of encryption to do so. Can anyone tell me how to do that ?

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> It doesn't store the secrets in plain text but it uses any kind of encryption to do so.

That's not the case. The secrets are stored in plain text. So just insert the shared secrets and identities as indicated on the referenced wiki page (using your example data):

```
/* type: ID_FQDN, data: arav */
INSERT INTO identities (type, data) VALUES (2, X'61726176');
/* type: SHARED_EAP, data: accessit */
INSERT INTO shared_secrets (type, data) VALUES (2, X'6361656373737469');
/* to associate the identity with the secret, use the actual ids of the two rows above */
INSERT INTO shared_secret_identity (shared_secret, identity) VALUES (1, 1);
```

Comment: I followed your steps but still receiving the same error
`Aug  4 11:42:03 ip-172-31-34-103 charon: 07[IKE] no EAP key found for hosts '52.15.108.115' - 'arav'`

Comment: the code in sql.conf file is 
`sql {
        load = yes
        database = mysql://ipsec:accessit@localhost/ipsec
    }`

Comment: Check the log for errors when the _sql_ plugin is initialized (make sure that it is actually loaded in the first place).

Comment: using ipsec statusall, it shows that it is being loaded, but I'm not sure whether it is pulling the secrets from the database or not? 

When i place my username in the database it get connected and when i dont, it refused to connect and says the authetication failed in logs.

Comment: You obviously have to associate the password with the username (as outlined in my answer), how else could the password be found?

Comment: I have added the password, i have added the entry in all 3 tables you explained. But still it is not working out

Comment: But you said above that it worked if you added the username to the database. What does that mean then exactly?

Comment: Ahh, sorry for the confusion, Actually when I added the secrets in ipsec.secrets file. It works fine.

But when I remove the secrets from the file and put it in the database, it doesn't.  Dont know what's wrong with it. I'm using MySQL database and I've added the mysql connection details in `/strongswan.d/charon/sql.conf`

Comment: Could you post a database dump?

Comment: Hi, I've posted all my configuration to this to represent a clear picture about my configurations.

https://pastebin.com/aPM7Yw5V

Comment: Do you actually have a `#` character in the DB password? That character is used for comments in the config files, try wrapping the complete DB connection string in quotes (`"`).

Comment: No luck, I've changed the password and removed the `#` and tried wrapping and unwrapping the connection string in `' '` . but still it didn't worked.

Here, I'm pasting the server log when i initiate a connection from a VPN client. Hope this will help.

https://pastebin.com/x5btFJLM

Can you please chat with me ? If possible. I'm new and I dont have enough reputation to initiate a chat.


This is the output of `ipsec statusall` command 
https://pastebin.com/YGB9aLbN

Comment: The _sql_ plugin is not loaded according to `ipsec statusall` (check the log for errors when the daemon starts).

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, Yes, here is the log when i do `ipsec restart` https://pastebin.com/kJSCSYsE .  both sql and mysql plugin should be loaded to run ? if it is not loaded , there might be some problem during the installation ? Any advice ?

Comment: Well, the _sql_ plugin is not loaded. And the log output seems awfully sparse (try [increasing log levels](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/LoggerConfiguration)). Perhaps the _sql_ plugin is not built/installed (if you built strongSwan yourself check previous configure arguments in config.log and make sure `--enable-sql` was included, if not run configure again, then build and install again after running `make clean` first).